# Switch type for electrical generator bonded to floating neutral

Tags: switches, generator, neutral

I have an electrical power generator and for it to properly work with it connected to the house it must be converted from bonded neutral to floating neutral according to [these](http://help.championpowerequipment.com/article/4etN4HzYKq-disconnecting-the-neutral-bond-to-frame) instructions. I was thinking of attaching a switch to be able to easily change from bonded and floating without having to remove the cover and wire each time I want to use the generator connected to the house or when using standalone.

I haven't found a simple toggle switch that can hold the max amp and voltage. I was then thinking of an [isolation switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B015KWSBJY) used on cars for batteries. I've seen some that can withstand 500 amps, but at 12 DC Volts. Would that work?
I want something small I can attach inside the housing.
Any recommendations and what specifications I should look for?

My Generator produces a max of 50 amps at 240 AC Volts.

The bonding cable is the top right white cable.
[image: Generator Housing]

Battery isolation switch
[image: Battery cut off switch]

Comment: I do hope when using the generator to power the house, you are using a proper isolator to avoid running in parallel with the mains supply.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not an electrician.  Don't listen to me.  USA.  Have you searched for a 'Safety Switch'.  They come in all sizes.  60Amp : $80.  Despot Depot: Home->Electrical->Power Distribution->Safety Switches

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not an electrician. Don't listen to me. USA. ...Also mechanical "Disconnect Switches" come in both fusible and non-fusible varieties.  Same $80/60A price point from the common online distributors. "Switch, Disconnect,600 VAC,4,65 mm,16 lb. in.,Extended/Direct Handle Motor"

Comment: @SimonB thought I could use both for extra power. I kid, of course, I have a 100 Amp Manual Transfer  Switch.

Comment: Single-pole or double-pole? Location information might help. Add it to your question or to your user profile.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen Thanks, but I'm looking for a small slimer option.

Comment: @Transistor It's just one neutral cable connected to the casing. So Single Pole...

Comment: If the generator isn't specifically designed to operate in grid-tied mode, then (a) it's probably illegal where you live to attempt to connect it to a live supply, and (b) if you did try it, something would go bang, most likely either the generator or your supply fuse.

Comment: My single-pole or double-pole question was about your transfer switch. Sorry.

Comment: @Transistor My Transfer switch is double pole.